# No output image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a infinite runner using JavaScript, CSS and HTML. When I run the code. No output image is shown.
The following code is what I have for HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" herf="style.css">
</head

</body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="block"/div>
  
  </div> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

The following code is what I have from CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#game{
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#character{
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-colour: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;

}
```

Comment: I don't see any images in the code provided. **</head** is a typo as it should be **</head>**. If that doesn't fix the problem, I would recommend checking out [mcve]. Body should have a start and end, you just have the end.

Comment: What errors do you get in your console? Should we assume that your script.js file is creating the runner game?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has a syntactical issue. This would be the correct HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" herf="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="block"/div>
  
  </div> 
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything you want to show up on the page needs to be within the `<body>` tag. The `</body>` closes the tag. You also had a typo in your `</head>` tag.

I assume when you say that there is "no output image" you mean that nothing is showing up in the browser window, this should fix that. It is worth mentioning that there are no `<img>` elements or anything like that, so you "character" will just be a red box on a white background.